# How to enable fullscreen mode for linux distros in virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, fullscreen

Recently I tried out installing various linux distros such as ubuntu mate ,pop os ,manjaro, windows,etc.in virtualbox .I installed virtual box guest additions in each one of them but was only successfull in case of windows 7. Please help me out on how to enable fullscreen for the linux distros. whenever I try to add virtualbox additions in linux os it shows an error. How do I resolve this. Please help .

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  (Pop OS, Manjaro, Windows are not *official* flavors of Ubuntu and thus off-topic on this site)

Comment: Sorry for the trouble . i will take care about this .

Comment: @guiverc ubuntu isn't off-topic

Comment: Can you tell us, what the error message says?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a custom resolution you can use `cvt` and `xrandr` to add and select it.

For example:

Get a modeline:

```
$ cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Create a new mode:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Get the correct monitor name:

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*HDMI-1 1280/376x1024/301+0+0  HDMI-1
```

Add the new mode to the monitor:

```
$ xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

Select the new mode.

```
$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
```

(You can use `xrandr -s 1920x1080` too)

(You have to run `xrandr --newmode ...`, `xrandr --addmode ...` and `xrandr --output ... --mode ...` every time you login)
(This doesn't work on Wayland)

Comment: thanks for the reply i will surely try this out.